# Is there a way to mark a method atomic?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, osx-lion

I'm implementing multi-threading in my ObjC program via NSBlockOperation.  Some of the method calls that are called within the block must be atomic.

Similar to making an @property nonatomic / atomic.

Is there anyway to mark the method as atomic (instead of using `@synthronized`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and it wouldn't make a difference anyways.  When you declare a `@property` as `atomic`, it only creates atomic accessors if you also `@synthesize` the accessors.  Otherwise, it's just a notice to client code that it's atomic, and you are responsible for writing accessors that are atomic (using `@synchronized` or other locks).

So even if you could declare a method as being atomic, you'll still have to write the atomic code yourself.

Answer (score 3):

No. The marking of a property atomic is actually just a hint to `@synthesize` that the code it emits for that property should use something along the lines of `@synchronized` to ensure that access to the property behaves atomically.

Note that in practice, the synthesized getter/setter need not actually use `@synchronized`. For example, if the underlying ivar can be read/written atomically without locks (e.g. a plain int on many platforms), there may be no actual locking generated by the compiler. The compiler is also free to use any other locking method rather than that used by `@synchronized`.